# Check bans function

Tags: php, mysql

I call this function on top of every page.
How would I do so it removes expired bans also? If current `time()` is more than expire field.
Would really appricate help.

bans

- id
- ip
- expire

(if expire is NULL its permanent)

function

```
function check_bans()
{

$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Se if users ip is banned
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM bans WHERE ip = '$user_ip'");

// If they are, kill script and show message
if (mysql_num_rows($query))
    die('You have been IP banished. Expires: <b>Never</b>');

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `expire` is a DATETIME data type, use:

```
SELECT ip, expire
  FROM bans 
 WHERE ip = '$user_ip'
   AND expire >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

NOW() works just as well - they're synonyms for the current date and time.

Comment: You should query for the ban expiry date rather than the IP. That way it can be used in the output to the user...

Answer (score 1):

```
function check_bans()
{
  $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT expire FROM bans WHERE ip='$user_ip' AND expire >= NOW()");
  if (mysql_num_rows($query) && $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    die("You have been IP banished. Expires: <b>".$row['expire']?$row['expire']:'Never'."</b>");
  }
}
```